# String.Replace() doesn't work

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-7

I am wondering why my string.replace doesnt work , it doesn't change the path of my string .

This is the code I am using :

```
WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
File theFile = new File();
theFile = (File)listBoxFiles.SelectedItem;

var newPath = theFile.Path;
newPath = newPath.Replace("C://inetpub//wwwroot//", "http://,mywebsite.com//Files//");
browser.URL = newPath;
browser.Show();
```

Comment: what are the values of theFile and newPath before and after the replacement?

Comment: They are the same, C://inetpub//wwwrooot// for the path .

Comment: I would expect a path in Windows to be `C:\\inetpub\\wwwrooot\\`, **not** `C://inetpub//wwwroot//`. Check the actual value you are getting in the debugger.

Comment: True , my mistake. In asp.net this doesn't matter, so since i'm workin on WP7 i always make this mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.Replace` almost certainly *does* work. It is most likely you that is mistaken.

Check the value of `newPath.Contains("C://inetpub//wwwroot//")` - if it's false it's because your string doesn't contain the string you are trying to replace.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound stupid but have you first debugged and checked what newpath is actually equal to because if you haven't and the string you are trying to replace doesn't exist its not that its not working its that there is no work to do.

Answer (score 1):

[`string.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) must work. I think `newPath` doesn't contain `"C://inetpub//wwwroot//"`. So try step by step to check, when you debug, the value of your string.

Maybe there isn't `"C://inetpub//wwwroot//"` but `"C://inetpub//wwwroot"`. So it depends.